# How to Modify Button Attributes in WPF Application Using VB.NET Code and Control Collection Iteration?

Tags: vb.net, collections, wpf-controls

I have written a WPF Application in VB.net.  My Startup URI is MainWindow.xaml.  The application is working fine.

However, I want to go back and use code to modify the attributes of some button controls.  Specifically, I want to change the buttontext.  To do this, I want to iterate through the controls collection to locate the buttons I want to change.

So I have entered this to iterate through the controls collection:

```
For Each myBtn as Control in Me.Controls

Next
```

But I get a message that says: "Controls is not a member of MainWindow".

I have searched for several days and have not been able to find an answer.

What am I doing wrong?...TIA.

Comment: I had seen this post, but didn't pursue it.  I'm not a VB programmer, just a retired guy who like to try his hand at it occasionally.  I'll see if I can convert the C# to VB and give it a try....Thanks.

Comment: https://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: I found some old code I had written 5 years ago, where I changed the button text.  All I needed to do was "button1.Content='newText'".  Works great!